# RPi 4 doesn't bring up wlan1

Tags: wifi, pi-4

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian 10 (buster) installed. This device will be placed in a waterproof metal box which will limit the on-board wifi range. So, I want to use a USB wifi adapter with an external antenna.

I have configured the on-board wifi adapter to connect to my wifi router successfully. **ifconfig** returns the following

```
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::512c:3a96:6ee9:d7c3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether dc:a6:32:1a:79:93  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 124  bytes 12486 (12.1 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 136  bytes 16805 (16.4 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My /etc/dhcpcd.conf file contains the following:

```
interface wlan0
    inform 192.168.1.10
    static routers=192.168.1.1
    static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
    metric 100;

interface wlan1
    inform 192.168.1.3
    static routers=192.168.1.1
    static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
    metric 200;
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant_wlan1.conf
```

My /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file contains:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
    update_config=1
    country=US

network={
        ssid="MYWIFI"
        psk="password"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

and the second wpa_supplicant.conf file contains the credentials for the same network with a different IP. However, when I do an **ifconfig** command **wlan1** never shows up.

The antenna I have is ASUS USB-AC56 which uses the Realtek RTL8812AU chipset. When I plug it into a USB port and run **lsusb** I get the following:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:17d2 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-AC56 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8812AU]
```

So the Pi sees the USB wifi adapter, but it doesn't bring up **wlan1**. What am I missing here?

EDIT to add the output of **ip -all link show**

```
pi@raspberrypi:/boot $ ip -all link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether dc:a6:32:1a:79:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state         UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
link/ether dc:a6:32:1a:79:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of this command to it: `ip -all link show`.

Comment: Hm.. not even a DOWN wlan1. Can you find something in `journalctl -b -e` maybe failing to load the firmware for the USB/WiFi dongle?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the on-board wifi use the Realtek RTL8812AU chipset?

Comment: No, on-board WiFi uses broadcom chip BCM4345/6. Check with `journalctl -b | grep brcmfmac`.

Comment: ... usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
If this is the broadcom driver it is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@Ingo** I got on the right path to finding my problem. I was not gettting a wlan1 because the correct driver was not installed. For the ASUS USB AC-56 I needed the Realtek RTL8812AU drivers installed.

From this [thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=194859), I was able to get the driver installed. Looks like **@MrEngman's** website has changed a little.

```
sudo wget http://fars-robotics.net/install-wifi -O /usr/bin/install-wifi
```

should be

```
sudo wget http://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/install-wifi -O /usr/bin/install-wifi
```

the rest of his instructions work as documented

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/install-wifi
sudo /usr/bin/install-wifiinstall-wifi -h # display help
sudo /usr/bin/install-wifiinstall-wifi -c # check to see if a driver exists
sudo /usr/bin/install-wifi # run the installer
sudo reboot
```

Now when I run **ifconfig**, **wlan1** shows up as expected.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.